How to connect several sheet symbols with [x...y] stye ports to a bus?
I have two ADC units within my hierarchical design. Each ADC unit have 16 inputs which I made with ADC[0..15] sheet port.
Is it even possible to use both units? Now I faced with the situation that each unit occupies ADC0...ADC15 "addresses".
The only thing I can see for the moment is to expand single ADC[0..15] sheet symbol port to multiple ADC0, ADC1, ..., ADC15 (in the same way as ADC_GPIO0...ADC_GPIO3 ports made) and rename each net as I want. But I don't have anough space for such big sheet symbols on my Top level sheet.
Are there any other solutions?


Can't you just rename the buses to ADC1[] and ADC2[] on the top level sheet? The port doesn't have to take precedence in net naming

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

@MrGerber what is the right name of this [] operator? I't like to read more about in the docs

The symbols are called Square brackets, but I don't know whether that gives you what you're looking for in the docs. I just didn't bother writing "ADC1[0..15]" and "ADC2[0..15]" from my cell phone. The point is that if you set your naming precedence rules in project options, the name of the bus can be the net name instead of the name of the bus nodes on the ADC hierarchical blocks
